# is there a way to do authenticate a user in a console application?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to write a console application that would extract some information from an authenticated user's facebook account and store it on the local machine in a text file. For this purpose, I need to be able to authenticate the user whose information will be extracted.

Now the issue is that all examples I find are using a web based authentication method that requires the browser. Is there any easier way to get a user's access token so that I can make authenticated API calls?

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Anything can pretend to be a browser, the issue is those methods most likely require some sort of javascript engine.  The easiest way for you might be to use the PHP (or other back-end) API and simulate the requests they do, but I imagine this would also be difficult. 
There exist a few third party C# libraries, such as [this one](http://facebooknet.codeplex.com/) that try to give access to the Facebook API.  That is likely the easiest (and perhaps best) route to take.  I have no idea how good this particular one is though.  You should try it, and perhaps look for others (keywords: .net library facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply ask users's to enter their FB credentials, make calls. If the credentials are wrong, then obviously they won't get their data back anyways and you can display the message accrodingly. (I assume that) Since the nature of the application is console, you dont need to persist user after API calls (like browser needs) so this should be fine.

Comment: I dont know of any mechanism that would simply take user credentials and retrieve the access token. Actually, that is my very question. How do I do that?

Comment: This might help you in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152225/automatic-login-to-facebook . I can't do more now because FB is blocked :)